# HTML content is pushed down when hovering over image

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a problem with the content inside a div (`.treatment`) that's pushed down when one hovers over the image:

```
.treatment {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 0 2.4rem;

  &__img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid $color-grey-light2;
    transition: border .2s;

    &:hover {
      border: 3px solid $color-action;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

Is there a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to the different `border` thickness, which is added to the original size.

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the CSS for the image, this *includes*   the border thickness in the elements width and height and helps to avoid that problem.

Comment: thanks. Coincidently I discovered this solution myself, but you were first : )